# How to fix that missing dependencies when run the python+playwright in the redhat

Tags: redhat, playwright-python

I am a newbieon the linux.
I got a mistake when I run my python with playwright in the Oracle Cloud.
How should I install the missing dependencies ?
Thanks for your help.

```
system info:
Playwright Version: [ 1.27.1 ]
Operating System: [ Red Hat Enterprise 8.6 (Ootpa) aarch64(Py3.7.8) ]
Pythonp version: [Python 3.9.15]
Browser: [ Chromium]
```

error text:

[image]

I have tried this, but not work.

```
    yum -y install libappindicator-gtk3
    yum -y install liberation-fonts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here (for me at least) is to use google to search for the missing items
and find the rpm package it is in:

```
libgbm.so.1 -> yum install mesa-libgbm
libdrm.so.2 -> yum install libdrm
libasound.so.2 -> yum install alsa-lib
```

My google search is usually something like "redhat libgbm.so.1"